# Changing the language for each individual site in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, language

I currently have a multisite setup and I currently have two sites, one is English (default) and the other I want it to be French. Since I can't have a separate config file and separate language folders I need to be able for each language site to use their respective .po file for the front end user. English for the backend is fine for both sites.

How can I do this? I don't see anywhere in the settings the selection of the language. Is there a plugin? Can I just add a simple line of code? Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the WPML plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the language files first, probably from http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp.

Then you get a language selector in **Settings/General**, where you can choose the site language.